# UI Automation Xcode instruments using javascripts

Tags: xcode-instruments

I am working on UI Automation using Xcode instruments, can anyone help me in how to remove additional information that shows in Extended Detail pane which usually includes a description of the probe or event that was recorded. Instead, it should show only the logger message which I have included in my scripts.

Thanks,
Vinod K

Comment: Hi Victor,
I have used the below mentioned statement to print it on Extended Detail pane of trace logs. However what I observed is. It is including the description of the probe or event that was recorded. (Ex: clicked on button, clicked on alert).

UIALogger.logPass("Connection Created");

So for the end user it shouldn't show the information about the probe or recorded event. It should only print the test case name and the status of it.

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Vinod Kumar K

Comment: Any updates on this victor?

Comment: Hi Victor, do you have any updates on this..

Comment: Sorry @vinod. I'm not familiar with the topic. I asked "what have you tried" to help other people about what direction they should take to answer you.

Comment: But, don't give up. Keep improving your question. Add more information about what you want to do. For example, what is this "additional information that shows in Extended Detail pane"? Do you have a image of this panel? Can you post an image or example of what you want to achieve?